# Canvas rectangle not adjusting to screen size

Tags: python, kivy

The background image is not adjusting to the screen size when used in py file, but adjust in kv file.

I tried changing the size of the Rectangle to Window.size, but then the image is not covering the whole screen.

Does canvas work differently outside of kv file?

Thanks for reviewing.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty, NumericProperty, BoundedNumericProperty, ListProperty, BooleanProperty

Config.set('graphics', 'window_state', 'maximized')

class FirstLayout(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FirstLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            Rectangle(pos = self.pos, size = self.size, source = 'test.jpg')

class SwitchButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SwitchButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.background_color = (20/255, 20/255, 20/255, 1)
        self.size_hint = None, None
        self.size = "100dp", "50dp"
        self.text = "Switch"
        self.pos_hint = {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.5}
        self.font_size = "22sp"

class First(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(First, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.firstlayout = FirstLayout()
        self.add_widget(self.firstlayout)
        self.switch_button = SwitchButton()
        self.add_widget(self.switch_button)

class Second(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Second, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        pass

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Manager, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(First(name = "first_screen"))
        self.add_widget(Second(name = "second_screen"))

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Manager()

TestApp().run()
```

Comment: In `.py` you have to handle it yourself by binding to a callback function. See in [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/graphics.html#manipulating-instructions).

Comment: Thank you very much. The Window however also doesn't open in 'maximized'. Where do I have to place the Config?

Comment: Try moving the `from kivy.config import Config` and the `Config.set('graphics', 'window_state', 'maximized')` to the first two lines `.py` file.

Comment: works. very nice :)